# How can I configure Quasar to transpile, serve and build just specific ES6 JavaScript files?

Tags: webpack, workbox, quasar-framework, workbox-webpack-plugin

The problem is the following (it comes from some constraints of the ServiceWorkers API):
The ServiceWorkers API currently does not support importing ES6 (It will in Chrome 80 but in the current stable version 79 it does not. This means that it will take more than a year for people to update their phones and browsers).

**I have to import some custom ES6 classes that will be used in a ServiceWorker.**

With it's default configifation Quasar will either serve a `/service-worker.js` file when running `quasar dev` or it will build one when running `quasar build`. It might be expected for Quasar to automatically transpile your `custom-service-worker.js` but sadly it does not. The following paragraph is an explanation for why it does not.

(To be more specific I am building a PWA.) The bad thing with Quasar is that for this purpose it uses `GoogleChrome/workbox` internally (Workbox's features are quite good for the project but as it happens with most Google products it's support is poor and it has 1-2 big drawbacks). See: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1513
So, under the hood Quasar uses their `workbox-webpack-plugin`. It consists of two classes named GenerateSW & InjectManifest.
**None of them are configurable in a way that automatic transpilation from ES6 to ES5 will happen.**

The solution for me is obviously to create another NPM\Webpack configuration and use it to build just these files without interfering with Quasar's configuration in any way.

The major drawback of the latter though, is that I will have to manually build (outside of Quasar) these custom ES6 classes that I am importing in the ServiceWorker (after they are transpiled). I.e it breaks the natural flow of Quasar (e.g. just using `qasar dev` and `quasar build`), and these files will be in active development for a long time (so it will hamper the development a lot).

I find it quite hard to find a starting point of reconfiguration. Configuring Webpack is quite complex and I haven't had quite a lot of time to tinker with it, so the context of Quasar makes it even a little bit more complex.

**How can I make Quasar to compile specific ES6 JavaScript files and serve them the way it serves its `app.js`, `client-entry.js` and `import-quasar.js` ? Is there such a way (If there is it will immediately solve my issues with the `workbox-webpack-plugin`)?
Any suggestions in the context of Quasar or Webpack?**